# Removed tomcat and environment variables but cd $CATALINA_HOME still looks for /opt/tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, catalina

Removed tomcat and environment variables but cd $CATALINA_HOME still looks for /opt/tomcat7 How do I remove it completely? I am using Cent OS6.5 I have removed it from /etc/profile as well as /usr/local/tomcat. I have removed the /opt/tomcat folder. What could I be missing?

Comment: How did you remove the environment variables?  Did you set a new environment variable for CATALINA_HOME with the correct value?

Comment: This might sound obvious but did you log out and back in to clear your environment? Sounds to me like you might still have CATALINA_HOME set in your current shell.

Comment: Well I have logged out and logged back in. But the problem didn't go away. SO I just renamed my folder to tomcat7 and pointed other environment variables(the ones I could find) to tomcat7 as well. Problemo solved